# rcp files from windows 2008 server to linux box? (Running rcp on linux)

Tags: windows-server-2008, linux-networking, rhel6, scp

I am trying to run rcp command on rhel6 server to copy over files from a windows 2008 server but see this error message.

/usr/bin/rcp administrator@10.225.185.112:"C:\nfsqa-rhel62-vm01.root.keytab" /etc/
rshd: unable to create process: The system cannot find the file specified.

Is there any security policy that needs to be changed on the windows server?

The same command goes through on the other windows server I have, this one is a old box.
/usr/bin/rcp administrator@10.225.187.40:"C:\nfsqa-rhel62-vm01.root.keytab" /etc/
[root@proto-rhel6-01 ~]#

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

Run [SysInternals Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) on the Windows server, then try the command. It will log what's happening, and show if the file access is denied, or if the file really isn't found (and what path the Windows process is ends up looking for).

Since it works on an older server, my guess is it's to do with UAC and accessing the C:\ root directory - try putting the file in a subfolder like `c:\keytabs\` and try that.

Comment: There is no default folder named keytabs, should I create one and give it all permissions?. The file exists but is not being picked up...

Comment: Either create the folder, or put the file somewhere that does exist - not a protected system folder. `c:\users\administrator\desktop` would probably work as you're connecting with the Administrator account. It's not being picked up for a reason - it's most likely because something isn't asking for the right file path in the right way, or because something is being denied access - SysInternals Process Monitor will tell you what process is asking for what file path, using what username, whether it's found, and whether access was allowed or denied.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I now see that the request is being received by the windows server on procmon.
This is what I see with the error message - NAME INVALID
C:\Windows\rcp -f C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\a.txt

But strangely that file does exist on the desktop - 
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\a.txt

Comment: Then maybe it's even simpler - does `c:\windows\rcp.exe` exist? Windows Server 2008 and newer don't come with rcp, it needs to be installed separately ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff698996.aspx ).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was able to succeed after installing this tool http://www.denicomp.com/rshdnt.htm